# Reading data recorded by Pi from an Android application?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, android

I'm creating a project that will notify a users Android device when their plant needs to be watered. I'm building the Android app myself using Android Studio. I'm using a Grove Pi moisture sensor to record the readings from the Pi coded in Python. I'm also using a USB WiFi dongle for RPi internet connection.

My problem is I'm not sure how to get the android application to access the information recorded from the Pi. Should I be using an intermediate server that the Pi posts to and the Android device reads from? If anybody could tell me what to do I would be eternally grateful and forever in your debt.

Thanks :)

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either option can work...

**Store The Info On The Pi**

For this the Pi will *have* to be accessible from the public internet (assuming you are not wanting it to alert *only* when the Pi and Android device are on the same network.

To make it publicly addressable you'll need a static ip (or dynamic dns client) and a domain name. It will also likely require port forwarding on your firewall/router - so that when the Android app checks http://yourdomain.com/doesmyplantneedwatered it can actually resolve where to find that server (your Pi) and connect to it.

Likely a web server on the Pi, which responds with the yes/no indicator.

---

**Store The Info On a Public IoT Data Logging Service**

This is *arguably* the *slightly* easier option. You create you own **channel** at one of the many IoT data logger services - this will hold the *status* on the plant (e.g. 0 = I'm fine, 1 = I need water) 
Write some code/script on your Pi to regularly grab the data from the sensor and send it to your channel - which can be achieved with something as simple as a curl POST.

The Android app checks the channel (parse the response to a simple http GET request) and alert as needed.

A couple of popular data loggers are https://data.sparkfun.com/ and https://thingspeak.com/

Comment: Sort of a separate answer, but also sort of a "1.b" option here: If the app only has to work locally, you could use a custom broadcast to discover the pi a la zeroconf/avahi, etc. (I think only Android 5+ actually implements zeroconf proper, something to investigate since it would make things easier).  No static ip, no need to configure the router.

Comment: @goldilocks Good point. I'm not sure about zeroconf/avahi on android though - I've not had it work successfully on 5, 6 or 7.... but maybe that's just me :-)

Comment: Neither have I but I did not try hard (port scanners apps will pick up on it -- awkward).  I noticed the thing about Lollipop in someone's blog when I did a quick search to double check this: https://medium.com/@_tiwiz/bonjour-android-its-zeroconf-8e3d3fde760e#.ravvcgyrv

Comment: Thanks for your clear and concise response, I will have a think about both options and then decide on an approach :)